# How do I check if email in trash or inbox or spam in .net core?

Tags: .net

I have this code ?

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
            MailboxAddress from = new MailboxAddress("Admin",
            "mohammad.jouhari33@gmail.com");
            message.From.Add(from);
            MailboxAddress to = new MailboxAddress("mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com",
            "mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(to);
            message.Subject = "This is email subject";
            BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
            bodyBuilder.TextBody = "Hello World!";
            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
            client.Authenticate("mohammad.jouhari33@gmail.com", "pptybpfunwthdgno");
            client.Send(message);
            client.MessageSent += OnMessageSent;
            var s = "";
            client.Disconnect(true);
            client.Dispose();
```

How do I check if email in trash or inbox or spam in .net core ?

Comment: if you mean "can I tell where this email ended up?" then the answer is - you have to log on to the destination email system as the target user

Comment: @pm can I do that in code using. Net core

Comment: https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/ex/c/7.aspx - i dont vouch for this being a good example tho

Comment: @pm100 noit working